# How to write a RSpec test for a link_to helper method?

Tags: rspec, helper, ruby-on-rails-6

I've done a feature to a nested form that when I click in a link, it calls a form from a partial.

Exemple:
In the new.html.erb(TaskList) when I create a new Task List, I can fill the name of the Task List and if I want to, I click on a link(`Add task`) to bring the Tasks form. So I can fill the Task List name and insert as many tasks as I want to.

I'll show the code related to it bellow:

new.html.erb (TaskList):

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <%= form.fields_for :tasks do |f| %>
    <%= render 'task_fields', f: f %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields('Nova tarefa', form, :tasks) %>
</div>

<script>
  $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(even){
    var regexp, time;
    time = new Date().getTime();
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));
    return event.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

task_lists_controller.rb :

```
def new
  @task_list = TaskList.new
  @task_list.tasks.build
end
```

_task_fields.html.erb :

```
<%= f.label :description, 'Tarefa:', class:"col-sm-2 mb-3" %>
<%= f.text_field :description, class:"form-control col-sm-10 mb-3" %>
```

application_helper.rb :

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)

    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new

    id = new_object.object_id

    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end

    link_to(name, '#', class: 'add_fields', data:{id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n","")})
  end
end
```

Task List has: user_id:references, name:string and status:integer(enum, with default value)

Tasks has: task_list_id:references, description:string and status:integer(enum, with default value)

Now I have to make a test(rspec) for the `link_to_add_fields` method in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`.